# ifstream reading in blanks when there is data in file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in data from a text file using c++ ifstream and for some reason the code below doesn't work. The file contains two numbers separated by a space. However this code doesn't print anything out. Could anyone explain to me what is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void readIntoAdjMat(string fname) {
    ifstream in(fname.c_str());
    string race, length;
    in >> race >> length;
    cout << race << ' ' << length << endl;  
    in.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    readIntoAdjMat("maze1.txt");
}
```

Comment: You should if you opened the file correctly and that you successfully read your entries. From the problem description I'd guess that it failed to open the file.

Comment: you don't actually check if the file opens properly. is it possible it's never opened?

Answer (score 2):

You should always test that interactions with external entities where successful:

```
std::ifstream in(fname.c_str());
std::string race, length;
if (!in) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to open '" + fname + "' for reading");
}
if (in >> race >> length) {
    std::cout << race << ' ' << length << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cerr << "WARNING: failed to read file content\n";
}
```

Comment: I think failing to read the file is an error. Not something you should warn about.

Comment: When using this it prints out "WARNING: failed to read file content\n". Why would if fail to read the contents of the file?

Comment: @user2640052: If there are, at least, two strings separated by a space in the file, it shouldn't fail. You might want read and test the individual fields to see which one causes the failure.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson: I'd think it depends. If it is crucial for the operation of the program to read the file, it is probably an error. If the file contains nice customizations to be applied, it may be OK if the content isn't well-formed.